# Нет перевода текста в комментариях при закрытии вопроса как дубликат

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

> Does this answer your question?

Надо бы перевести:

> Возможный дубликат

Например, в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064425) вопросе.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите скрин, а лучше ещё ссылку на такой вопрос)

Comment: @Suvitruf [example](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1064425/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-framework-kivy-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0)

Comment: Ещё неплохо бы тогда и в самом дубликате перевести This question already has answers here: (В том же примере) )

Comment: @Denis640Kb причины закрытий многие не переведены. Уже есть вопросы про это)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13674

Вернул старый текст:

> Возможный дубликат вопроса:

С новой ревизией движка должно появиться.

Comment: Двоеточие не лишнее?

Comment: @Qwertiy раньше там всегда было двоеточие.

Comment: Но это не мешает его убрать при желании ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy ну глянь [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/676882/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82#comment989085_676882). Без `:` не очень будет (: